# Call my Search results view with valid parameters from search

Tags: django

I have a function which puts up a search template and when the search template is completed and valid, calls my search results view which generates the result based on the completed parameters in the response.  My problem is I used render to put up the search results page,
and the URL does not change (ie. the URL still says get_search, instead of search_results..).
It means that the pagination won't work because it doesn't have the correct URL.

What should I use to pass the response to the search results view and change the URL.  Attempted reverse_lazy but as I expected it gave me an attribute error - '**proxy**' object has no attribute 'get'.

My function is below:

```
def get_search(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    request.method = "GET"
    request.GET = request.POST
    if form.is_valid():
      return SearchResultsView.as_view()(request)
  else:
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.is_valid():
      return SearchResultsView.as_view()(request)
    else:
      form = SearchForm(request.GET)

  return render(request, 'get_search.html', {'form':form})
```

The search Results view is pretty lengthy but the beginning of the search_results view looks like this:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
#
      segment_results = None
      program_results = None
      segment_program_list = None

      query = self.request.POST.get('q')
      start_date = self.request.POST.get('start_date')
      end_date = self.request.POST.get('end_date')
      svc_choices = self.request.POST.getlist('service_choices')
   .
   .
   .
```

The urls look like

```
    path('get_search/', get_search, name='get_search'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

Comment: Why don't you set the action of the form used in the view `get_search` to the url of `SearchResultsView`? This way the form _itself_ will be submitted to the correct view. Please show your template (where the form is). Or simply _redirect_ the user to the second view with GET parameters.

Comment: I tried to use the action search_results - but when I hit search it immediately went to the Search Results view. No validation was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user from `get_search/` to `search/` while having the search parameters as a querystring or GET parameters:

```python
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse


def get_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = '{}?{}'.format(reverse('search_results'), request.POST.urlencode())
            return redirect(url)
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        # You might want to remove the next 4 lines? they don't appear very logical to me, ideally in the GET method you render the form, in POST you process it.
        if form.is_valid(): # You check the form validity for both types of requests??
            return redirect('search_results')
        else:
            form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    return render(request, 'get_search.html', {'form':form})
```

Next in your `SearchResultsView` simply use the GET parameters:

```python
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        segment_results = None
        program_results = None
        segment_program_list = None

        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        start_date = self.request.GET.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.request.GET.get('end_date')
        svc_choices = self.request.GET.getlist('service_choices')
        ...
```